# Auth0 Implementation is not populating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, frontend, auth0

I have tried to implement Auth0 into my current ReactJS application and it is just not populating for some reason.  I am seeing the username and password fields in the top left corner of the application.

I just don't see my Auth0 sign in page rendering with the correct styles and all.

[THIS IS WHAT I CURRENTLY SEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVIrr.png)

I will put any of the relevant code files below here

I will be working on this all day.  I can provide any other sorts of code to help fix this issue.

I appreciate all of your guys help here.

---

`routes.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home/Home';
import Callback from './Callback/Callback';
import Auth from './Auth/Auth';
import history from './history';

const auth = new Auth();

const handleAuthentication = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(nextState.location.hash)) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
}

export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history} component={App}>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" render={(props) => <App auth={auth} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/home" render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/callback" render={(props) => {
          handleAuthentication(props);
          return <Callback {...props} /> 
        }}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  goTo(route) {
    this.props.history.replace(`/${route}`)
  }

  login() {
    this.props.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.props.auth.logout();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { renewSession } = this.props.auth;

    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true') {
      renewSession();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
    // const { bsStyle, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js"></script>

        <Navbar fluid="true">
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="#">Auth0 - React</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Button
              // bsStyle="primary"
              className="btn-margin"
              onClick={this.goTo.bind(this, 'home')}
            >
              Home
            </Button>
            {
              isAuthenticated() ? (
                  <Button
                    id="qsLogoutBtn"
                    // bsStyle="primary"
                    className="btn-margin"
                    onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}
                  >
                    Log Out
                  </Button>
              ) : (
                <Button
                  id="qsLoginBtn"
                  // bsStyle="primary"
                  className="btn-margin"
                  onClick={this.login.bind(this)}
                >
                Log In
                 </Button>
              )
            }
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`index.js`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { makeMainRoutes } from './routes';

const routes = makeMainRoutes();

ReactDOM.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`Auth.js`

```
import history from '../history';
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth0-variables';

export default class Auth {
  accessToken;
  idToken;
  expiresAt;

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
    redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    scope: 'openid'
  });

  constructor() {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this);
    this.getAccessToken = this.getAccessToken.bind(this);
    this.getIdToken = this.getIdToken.bind(this);
    this.renewSession = this.renewSession.bind(this);
  }

  login() {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }

  handleAuthentication() {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult);
      } else if (err) {
        history.replace('/home');
        console.log(err);
        alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`);
      }
    });
  }

  getAccessToken() {
    return this.accessToken;
  }

  getIdToken() {
    return this.idToken;
  }

  setSession(authResult) {
    // Set isLoggedIn flag in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');

    // Set the time that the access token will expire at
    let expiresAt = (authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime();
    this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
    this.idToken = authResult.idToken;
    this.expiresAt = expiresAt;

    // navigate to the home route
    history.replace('/home');
  }

  renewSession() {
    this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
       if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
         this.setSession(authResult);
       } else if (err) {
         this.logout();
         console.log(err);
         alert(`Could not get a new token (${err.error}: ${err.error_description}).`);
       }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    // Remove tokens and expiry time
    this.accessToken = null;
    this.idToken = null;
    this.expiresAt = 0;

    // Remove isLoggedIn flag from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn');

    // navigate to the home route
    history.replace('/home');
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    // Check whether the current time is past the
    // access token's expiry time
    let expiresAt = this.expiresAt;
    return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }
}
```

`auth0-variables.js`

```
export const AUTH_CONFIG = {
  domain: '{dev-32ro5agk.auth0.com}',
  clientId: '{V1Kba5uTmKvUgnX8gnkXZ8iYsYYYA6Qb}',
  callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Removing curly braces from domain and clientid in `auth0-variables.js` fixed the problem for me

```
export const AUTH_CONFIG = {
domain: 'dev-32ro5agk.auth0.com',
clientId: 'V1Kba5uTmKvUgnX8gnkXZ8iYsYYYA6Qb',
callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
}
```